# DevExpress Xtragrid gridview inside gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, gridcontrol

I want to fill a cell of a DevExpress Xtragrid gridview with another gridview. Is this possible? and if its possible can someone help me with this like what should I read about for doing this..

Comment: This sounds like an *exceptionally* confusing user interface...

Comment: thats because I need some cells in a column with two combo boxes and the remaining cells with a single combo box.. So I thought I will create another gridview with two columns (combo box each) and place that gridview in the necessary cells..

Comment: you can use master detail grid view to display details in another view ..  Check this [link](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=xtragrid+master-detail+grid&p=T4|P1|0&d=29) search result for your implementation.

Comment: Check these also [master-detail overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument783) and [this](http://search.devexpress.com/default.aspx?q=xtragrid+master-detail+view&p=T4|P1|0&d=157&page=2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need some cells in a column with two combo boxes and the remaining cells with a single combo box

As far as I can see your collection row object has a property, which is an object with its own properties: for example the row object is Person and it has an Address property, which in turn has City, Street and Zip properties. And you want to display and edit subproperties of the Person.Address property in the grid. I believe that embedding of gridview into grid cell it is not a good idea. Instead of this you can [embed a custom editor into grid cell](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E3051.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

DevEx allows you to set [Master-Detail relationships](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3473) in your GridViews that will be very similar to what you're looking for.